# A problem on simple congruences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a problem on congruences given in the book of Andy Liu, titled "Arithmetical Wonderland".

A Dragon has $100$ heads, and it can only be killed if all its heads are cut off. A Prince has two swords. The long one can cut off exactly $21$ heads of the Dragon at a time. The short one can cut off exactly $4$ heads of the Dragon at a time, but every time this sword is used, the Dragon grows another $1985$ heads. The Prince must be careful not to leave the Dragon with $1, 2$ or $3$ heads, as his swords will be useless then. Can the Prince kill the Dragon?

My attempt:
As $100/21$ should give remainder, which can be minimum $16$.
It means that the short sword need be used too. 
The additional condition seems useless unless the linear combination of $21x+4y$ can achieve a value of $99, 98,$ or $97$, for which the second additional condition of growing $1985$ heads on cutting snake by smaller sword should be applicable.

So, framing the equality : $100 = 21x + 4y$, we get solution for $x= 4, y =4$. 
But, this framing of equality is wrong, as the $\gcd$ of $21,4=1$, and so it can be only $100=2100x +400y$.

Additional condition of growing $1985$ heads seems difficult to combine with the same equality. How should I frame equations such that the both additional conditions fit together in the same equality, is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each cut with the short sword adds a net of 1981 heads (+1985 -4). Simply take 100+1981y = m. Then use modular arithmetic to determine if m is ever $0 \mod 21$ or $4 \mod 21$. There you can prove or disprove.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Taking the modulus of both sides (as the answer has only taken of the r.h.s.), get: $16 + 7y = m$. So, the value of $y$ should make any multiple of  $\gcd$ of $16, 7y = m$. It seems that I need to take the congruence w.r.t. $21$ again, as sum of $16+7y \mod 21$ should be $m$.  Before, trying out possible values for $y$ in naturals, such that $m=0,$ or $4$; we can see what are the possible residue classes of $16+7y \pmod{21}$, and see that the values we get are: $23(\equiv 2), 9, 16, 2$. This cycle goes on and on, so the prince is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   h_0 &= 100 \\
   h_{i+1} &= h_i + (-21 \ \text{or} \ 1981)
\end{align}

We note that $\gcd(-21,1981)=7$ and $100 = 2 \pmod 7$. It follows that, for all $i$, $h_i = 2 \pmod 7$. It follows that we can never cut off all of the heads of the dragon.

### Response to a comment

If the $21$ had been a $29$, then we would get this sequence of head counts

\begin{align}
   h_0 &= 100 \\
   h_{i+1} &= h_i + 
      \begin{cases}
         -29   & \text{if 29 heads are cut off.} \\
         1981  & \text{if 4 heads are cut off.} \\
      \end{cases}
\end{align}

The simplest strategy would be to cut off four heads until there are a multiple of 29 heads on the dragon. So we need to solve the congruence equation

\begin{align}
   1981x \equiv -100 \pmod{29} \\
   9x \equiv 16 \pmod{29} \\
   x \equiv 5 \pmod{29}
\end{align}

So we chop off $4$ heads $5$ times in a row. We get $h_0 = 100$ and 
$h_5 = 10005 = 345 \cdot 29$. We cut of $29$ heads $345$ times and end up with 
$h_{350}=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this novel approach. I have some confusion regarding the answer: There is a series generated with the next term being defined by the earlier term, among two other mutually exclusive quantities. This approach relies on the residue classes being in the forbidden set of values. But, had the two values were instead: $-29, 1981$, then their $\gcd=1.$ Then, how to pursue this approach is not clear. Please help.

Comment: For the problem as stated either 21 heads get cut off or (-4+1985) heads get added at the end of each "time". So, for this problem, there will always be 7m+2 heads for some integer m.

Comment: If I modify the problem, so that the $\gcd=1,$ as done in my first comment to your answer, by choosing $-29$ and $1981$, then your approach seems not to work. I mean that in the new case (created by me), either $29$ heads get cut off or $(-4+1985)$ heads get added at the end of each sword movement.

Comment: @jitender Then you cut off 4 heads until the dragon has a multiple of 29 heads. That will turn out to be 5 times. Then just chop of 29 heads at a time until there are none left (345 times).

Comment: Thanks for that. Your modified answer has shown the same approach as your 'earlier' answer, with difference that now $(29,1981)=1$. Hence, $100=0(mod 1)$. So, the last two lines of your 'earlier' answer can be modified for the 'new' case as:" It follows that, for all $i, h_i=100=0 \pmod 1.$ It follows that we can cut off all of the heads of the dragon. " ----Also, my approach is given next. Please vet it : $1981y + 100 \pmod 29 \implies 9y+13 \pmod 29$. The set of residue values are $=13, 22, 2, 11, 20, 0$. So, $5$ times need to use the smaller sword to get success by bigger sword.